# How to collect the logs and output from a program and pass them into the parameter of a function

Tags: bash, shell, sh, embedded-linux

I have a shell script which has a function to Log statements

```
#!/bin/sh

Log() {
    echo $1 >> /some/logfile
}

Log "Test logging works"
```

This works great!

Next, I have a program which logs statements and if I want to have the logs from there added into a file, I can do like this

```
SomeProgram >> SomeFile.txt
```

This also works great!

But, what if I want to pass the logs from `SomeProgram` into my function `Log` while calling `SomeProgram` from the same shell script. Is that possible? Following are some tricks I tried which didn't work.

```
Log "SomeProgram >> SomeFile.txt"
Log(SomeProgram >> SomeFile.txt)
```

**Question**
So, how can I collect the logs from a program and keep passing them into the parameter of a function?

**Environment:**
Linux

Comment: `Log "$(./SomeProgram)"` does that not work? The output of SomeProgram should be passed to Log. I'm not sure what SomeFile.txt has to do with what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which will handle standard input as well as any arguments:

```sh
Log() {
  # if STDIN (0) is not a terminal, iterate over any lines of standard input
  [[ ! -t 0 ]] && while read line; do echo "$line" >> /some/logfile; done

  # iterate over any arguments provided
  for arg; do echo "$arg" >> /some/logfile; done
}
```

If you have a program that will continuously output lines of text, you can pipe `|` that program's standard output to your function's standard input, feed it arguments manually, or both!

```sh
SomeProgram | Log
Log "line one" "line two"
SomeProgram | Log "additional line one" "additional line two"
```

Check out `man bash`, `/^ *Compound Commands` for all types of syntax that will work with functions.

Comment: `while read -r line || [[ ${line} ]]; do` because otherwise it will skip a line not ending with a newline

Comment: The idiomatic way is `while IFS= read -r line`, so that leading and trailing whitespaces are not omitted.

Comment: @vintnes I updated the question description to refer it as "function" not "method" anymore

Comment: Checking if stdin is a tty is a bad idea. Now if the user runs the script in a pipeline it's going to suck up all the input as log messages.

Comment: It will starve any other commands that try to read stdin. For example, if the script says `Log "asking for username"; read -p 'user: ' user`, the `Log` call will consume `read`'s input if stdin isn't a tty. The user may be trying to automate answering the prompt with `echo "bob" | ./script`.

Comment: It'd be better to check for an argument like `SomeProgram | Log --stdin`.

Comment: `SomeProgram | Log` works with the `Log` function modification done in this answer. @vintnes You modified the function to iterate multiple parameters so that we can include what is passed in as a param as well as the std output . Correct?

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg correct. Note that this is procedural; if you wanted your arguments to be logged first, you would place that line first in the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess the answer can be improved if the discussion above arrives at something better. But, I accepted the answer anyways, since this works very well for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a one off case I'd write a loop.

```
SomeProgram | while IFS= read -r line; do
    Log "$line"
done
```

If you're going to be doing it a lot you could add a second mode to `Log` where it reads from stdin instead of its arguments.

```
Log() {
    case $1 in
        --stdin)
            while IFS= read -r line; do Log -- "$line"; done
            return;;

        --)
            shift;;
    esac

    echo "$*" >> /some/logfile
done
```

```
SomeProgram | Log --stdin
```

---

*Do not [check if stdin is a tty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56834501/68587)! Doing so would cause `Log()` to consume stdin any time your script is called non-interactively. Good scripts behave well when automated and used in pipelines; they don't insist on keyboard input.*

Answer (score -1):

use `tee` to split output

```
Log "$(SomeProgram | tee -a SomeFile.txt)"
```

Explanation:

`SomeProgram | tee` pass the stdio output from `SomeProgram` to the `tee` command

`tee -a SomeFile.txt` will output to stdio and at the same time `-a` add to `SomeFile.txt`

`Log "$(......)"` will capture stdio of commands inside the parenthesis and pass the result as parameter to the `Log` function.

Comment: Command Substitution will wait for SomeProgram to finish before passing a value, which is undesirable for ongoing logging.